# Is it Possible to Return to a Neutral Vote State?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

If I've down-voted something, and then later I come back and see an improved answer that

1. I wouldn't have down-voted
2. **but** still doesn't rise to an answer I feel is worth an upvote

is there a way to return my vote to a neutral state?

I'm not advocating for or against the behavior, I'm just wondering if its possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - just click on the down-vote arrow again. As long as you're inside the vote window or the post has been edited your down-vote will be removed. You'll even get your 1 point of rep back.

The same applies to up-votes as well of course (apart from the bit about the rep).

It actually says this on the tooltip you get when you hover over the voting arrows (which I forgot and should have added sooner).

Comment: Kind of weird to think about the voting as a toggle mechanism, but once you know about it it makes sense.